# The closure of meromorphic functions under composition

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

It is well-known that composing meromorphic functions on $\mathbb C$ *does not* necessarily result in a meromorphic function (e.g., $\exp\circ\frac1x$, which has an essential singularity at $x=0$.)

**Question:** What is the "closure" of the meromorphic functions under composition? That is, what is the minimal extension field $K$ of the field $\mathcal M(\mathbb C)$ such that for each $f,g\in K\setminus\mathbb C$, we have $f\circ g\in K$.

My naïve guess would be the field of holomorphic functions defined on $\mathbb C\setminus I$, for some zero-dimensional complex analytic subset $I$. Such a field will be certainly closed under composition, but I am not sure how to prove/disprove it is *minimal*.

---

Here, I view meromorphic functions as entire functions $f\colon\mathbb C_\infty\setminus\{\infty\}\to\mathbb C_\infty$, where $\mathbb C_\infty:=\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ is the Riemann sphere. Then, we can define the composition of entire functions $f\colon\mathbb C_\infty\setminus I\to\mathbb C_\infty$ and $g\colon\mathbb C_\infty\setminus J\to\mathbb C_\infty$ with $f\circ g\colon \mathbb C_\infty\setminus(J\cup g^{-1}(I))\to\mathbb C_\infty:z\mapsto f(g(z))$.

Comment: I think it should be sufficient that $I$ be countable. The functions in $\mathcal M(\Bbb C)$ have at most a single essential singularity at $\infty$. A non-constant meromorphic function takes on any value only countably many times, so the number of "copies" of an essential singularity produced by compositions can also only be countable.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Now, again, the problem is whether that is minimal. Given a countable set $I\subset\mathbb C$, using a Weierstrass factorization argument you can (probably) produce a function $f$ with zeroes at $I$, so $\exp\circ1/f(x)$ will certainly have essential singularities at $I$. However, I have no idea how to prove *any* such function is realizable as a composition of meromorphic functions.

Comment: The problem is, countable sets can be dense, and if a function has a dense set of "essential singularities", then it is no longer analytic anywhere.

Comment: I see. Since meromorphic functions are continuous, the pullbacks of $\infty$ should always be closed, so we can probably assume $I$ is a countable *closed* subset.

Comment: That works for poles, but not essential singularities. Per Picard, the image of every neighborhood of an isolated essential singularity under the function will consist of all of $\Bbb C$, except possibly for two points. Meromorphic functions do not behave anything similar to "continuous" at essential singularities.